# Iterate through two loops when building the JSON String

Tags: json, list, groovy

I am invoking a restful service to get the available documents on the the server where I am getting the JSON as s response. I am building the JSON String with the JSONBuilder so when invoking the this link

http://localhost:8080/httpConnector/Rest/Documents?Accept=application/json

I am getting the JSON String below:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "result": {
                "name": "Test traisy",
                "version": "sdvdsv",
                "author": "sdvdsv"
            }
        },
        {
            "result": {
                "name": "Jaspersoft Ultimate guide",
                "version": "sdfdsv",
                "author": "sdvdsv"
            }
        },
        {
            "result": {
                "name": "Dohrn",
                "version": "12.19.00",
                "author": "sdfdsf"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

**Code**

```
String accept = getValue("Accept");
accept = "application/xml";                
if ("application/xml".equals(accept)){
    builder=new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer);
}else{
    builder=new groovy.json.JsonBuilder();
}

   builder{
    results foaList.collect{
        [
                  //Here I want to loop through the otaList to do something like that "ota.getName(), foa.getFlexiObject().getByString(ota.getName())"
          result:   [
                  name: it.getFlexiObject().getByString("name"),
              version: it.getFlexiObject().getByString("version"),
               author: it.getFlexiObject().getByString("author")
                ] 
        ]
    }

}
```

Now I want to add the properties programatically. Therefore I have to loop through the otaList to do something like that

```
builder.'results'() {
    for(FlexiObjectAttachment foa: foaList){
        for(ObjectTypeAttribute ota : otaList){
            param.put(ota.getName(), foa.getFlexiObject().getByString(ota.getName()));

        }
        result(param);
    }       
}
```

this version just works for the xml respose.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to do the combination of `foa` and `ota` directly in your `collect` call.
That way your initially created dict would have the correct structure.

Something like the example below

```
def foaList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def otaList = ['A', 'B', 'C']

foaList.collect { foa ->
    result = [name: "Name$foa", version: "v$foa", author: "Author$foa"]
    otaList.each { ota -> result[ota] = "$ota$foa" }
    [ result: result ]
}
```